# Capturing the image url when drag and drop it from browser window in Visual Basic

Tags: javascript, image, firefox, vbscript, event-handling

I need to create a simple script to capture the image URL dragged from one browser window to another in Visual Basic. I will drag and drop picture on google search engine. I make a macro in the Macro ToolsWorks program and there is no such function but I can attach there a Visual Basic Script or JavaScript. I need to assign an url of dragged image to a variable, to automate some operations such as changing the paths in the html files later. I don't know the Visual BASIC at all, so please help me. I'm using Firefox and Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript can't perform these functions. You want [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) and javascript.

Comment: VBScript can do that as well [link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=558544) but I need handle url and assign to variable in Macro ToolsWorks somehow.

Comment: And there is some function that can send data from basic script code to native macro    Sub Main
    ChanNum = DDEInitiate("MacroEngine","MacroSetVar")
             Var = "vVar=Hello from Basic script!"
    DDEExecute (ChanNum, Var)
    DDETerminate ChanNum
End Sub

Comment: but how to join everything all together and how to control it.

Comment: This works because they are doing it in Internet Explorer via HTA. Sorry, but what you want to do is not possible.

Comment: Thanks anyway. So I must to find solution in another way.